# CC.Net NCover exclude assemblies

Tags: c#, tdd, cruisecontrol.net, ncover

I have a CC.Net with ncover reports with a project that contains different assemblies.

The things is that I want only to have ncover reports only from the "main" project and not other dll like a Businessframework that is tested in another project.

It seems that ncover-console has a exclude type to perform that but It doesn't work because all the missing test from that Businessframework are also shown.

This is the coverage.cmd executed

```
"C:\Program Files\TestDriven.NET 3\NCover\1.5.8\NCover.Console.exe" //x coverage.xml //et SER.Businessframework.* "C:\Program Files\NUnit 2.5.10\bin\net-2.0\nunit-console.exe"   "C:\DEVProjects\build\PL\SER.PLine.Test\bin\Debug\SER.PLine.Test.dll"
"C:\Program Files\TestDriven.NET 3\NCoverExplorer\NCoverExplorer.Console.exe" coverage.xml /r:ModuleSummary /xml
```

To summarize, I guess that perhaps the way I'm telling ncover to exclude a project is now well done:

```
//et SER.Businessframework.*
```

Comment: Did you try the solution from http://www.ncover.com/forum/show_topic?id=444 ? (xsl fix at the end of the page)

Comment: Haven't tried it, BTW tried without success.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to exclude certain assemblies from the coverage analysis, the commandline option is (assuming the assembly filenames match the following pattern)

```
// eas SER.Businessframework.*
```

Here's the link to the relevant manual page[enter link description here](http://docs.ncover.com/ref/3-0/ncover-console/command-line/profiling-options#eas). I do not have NCover installed at the moment, but this used to work when I last tried it.

Comment: In build log says `Unrecognized command line option: //eas` maybe because it's a Complete Edition Feature and I don't have one of these?